# Referring to package and function as arguments in another function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to find methods for specific functions across different packages in R. For example `methods(broom::tidy)` will return all methods for the function `tidy` in the package `broom`. For my current issue it would be better if I could have the `methods` function in another function like so:
`f1 <- function(x,y){
 methods(x::y)
}`

(I removed other parts of the code that are not relevant to my issue.)
However when I run the function like this:

```
f1 <- function(x,y){ methods(x::y)}
f1(broom,tidy)
```

I get the error

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘x’

If I try to modify it as to only change the function but keep the package the same I get a similar error :

```
f2 <- function(y){  methods(broom::y)}
f2(tidy)
```

> Error: 'y' is not an exported object from 'namespace:broom'

How can I get the package and function name to evaluate properly in the function? Does this current issue have to do with when `r` is trying to evaluate/substitute values in the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both the `::` and `methods()` functions use non-standard evaluation in order to work. This means you need to be a bit more clever with passing values to the functions in order to get it to work. Here's one method

```
f1 <- function(x,y){ 
  do.call("methods", list(substitute(x::y)))
}
f1(broom,tidy)
```

Here we use `substitute()` to expand and `x` and `y` values we pass in into the namespace lookup. That solves the `::` part which you can see with

```
f2 <- function(x,y){ 
  substitute(x::y)
}
f2(broom,tidy)
# broom::tidy
```

We need the substitute because there could very well be a package `x` with function `y`. For this reason, variables are not expanded when using `::`. Note that `::` is just a wrapper to `getExportedValue()` should you otherwise need to extract values from namespaces using character values.

But there is one other catch: `methods()` doesn't evaluate it's parameters, it uses the raw expression to find the methods. This means we don't actually need the value of `broom::tidy`, we to pass that literal expression. Since we need to evaluate the substitute to get the expression we need, we need to build the call with `do.call()` in order to evaluate the `substitute` and pass that expression on to `methods()`

Comment: how do I convert `f2(dplyr, between)` into a function? It returns unevaluated function call. Something along the lines of ` `f2(dplyr, between)(1,2,3)`

Comment: @slava-kohut.  Well, you could call `\`::\`(dplyr, between)(1,2,3)` directly or you could `eval()` the expression `eval(f2(dplyr, between))(1,2,3)`

Comment: the latter is what I asked. Thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick random but is there a pure`rlang` solution? I tried to replace `substitute` with `enexpr` or `enquo` but get errors that arg must be a symbol. I originally thought that  `substitute` was identical to `enexpr` in `rlang` but I realize now `substitute`  might have more features.

Comment: @Mike This is the only way I could get it to work for rlang: `f3 <- function(x,y){ x <- rlang::ensym(x); y <- rlang::ensym(y);rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::quo(methods(`::`(!!x, !!y))))}` The parse seems to be a bit quirky around the `::` operator.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you! I think I will stick with `substitute` but I appreciate the `rlang` solution!