# True difference between rlang::enexpr and base::substitute

Tags: r, rlang

This question is related to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452820/referring-to-package-and-function-as-arguments-in-another-function/58453284?noredirect=1#comment105669081_58453284).

**In short I am looking for why `base::substitute` and `rlang::enexpr` are behaving differently below.**

```
#works
f1 <- function(x,y){ 
  do.call("methods", list(substitute(x::y)))
}
f1(broom,tidy)
#does not work
#Error: `arg` must be a symbol
f2 <- function(x,y){
  do.call('methods',list(rlang::enexpr(x::y)))
}
f2(broom,tidy)
```

The longer version. In the advanced R book [chapter 19](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) you can see tables 19.1 and 19.2 suggest that `enexpr` and `substitute` should serve the same purpose in a function call (I could be wrong here and would be happy with an explanation on why I am wrong).

I decided to test this out and saw that in `f1` returns results but `f2` returns an error.

Interestingly, if you use `do.call('methods',list(rlang::expr(broom::tidy)))` this works. I find this interesting because `rlang::expr` simply calls `rlang::enexpr`.

In the question above, MrFlick posted this function as a pure rlang solution

```
#also works 
#function from MrFlick in the posted link
f3 <- function(x,y){
x <- rlang::ensym(x)
y <- rlang::ensym(y)
rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::quo(methods(`::`(!!x, !!y))))}

f3(broom,tidy)
```

This seems to be a bit more complicated than I was expecting.

It would be helpful to know why `f1` and `f2` are not equivalent or how to make `f2` work with `enexpr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rlang::enexpr()` and `base::substitute()` are not quite equivalent in their interface. `enexpr()` expects a single variable name that refers to one of the function's input argument, whereas `substitute()` can work with arbitrary expressions. This requires additional expression arithmetic -- by wrapping with `rlang::expr()` and using unquote operator `!!` --  to place the result of `enexpr()` into a more complex expression:

```
g  <- function(x) substitute(x+5)
h  <- function(x) rlang::enexpr(x+5)
h2 <- function(x) rlang::expr( !!rlang::enexpr(x) + 5 )

g(a)   # a + 5
h(a)   # Error: `arg` must be a symbol
h2(a)  # a + 5
```

To make `f2` work, you need to apply `rlang::enexpr()` to each argument separately, then use expression arithmetic to compose the overall `x::y` expression:

```
f2 <- function(x,y){
   ee <- rlang::expr( `::`(!!rlang::enexpr(x), !!rlang::enexpr(y)) )
   do.call('methods',list(ee))
}
f2(broom,tidy)
```

Note that we have to use `::` in prefix notation, because having `!!` and `::` next to each other is a problem for the parser. In other words, expressions of the type `!!a :: !!b` result in parsing errors.

The alternative is to let the user compose the expression themselves. This way you can get away with a single `rlang::enexpr()`:

```
f3 <- function(x)
  do.call('methods',list(rlang::enexpr(x)))
f3( broom::tidy )
```

**Side Note:**

Even though `expr()` calls `enexpr()`, that call is with respect to the scope of `expr()` itself. Consider,

```
f1 <- function(x)  rlang::enexpr(x)

f2 <- function(x) {
  g <- function(y) rlang::enexpr(y)
  g(x)
}
```

The two are not equivalent, because the second `enexpr()` is scoped to the inner function `g()`, not to the outer `f2()`.

```
f1(abc)   # abc
f2(abc)   # x
```