# use rlang::call2 to get a variable, not a function, from a package

Tags: r, rlang

I am writing an R package and I would like to avoid explicit dependency on a particular package (otherwise my package would have an unwieldy number of package dependencies).

`rlang::call2()` is widely used to call functions from another R package without triggering a dependency on that other package. This strategy is used e.g. in `parsnip` from the `tidymodels` framework.

However, I am interested in retrieving a *variable* from a package, not a function.

How can I use `rlang::call2()` to retrieve a *variable* from a namespace?

For a *function* `bar()` from package `foo`, I can use `rlang::call2()` in the standard way, like this:

```
call <- rlang::call2(.fn="bar",.ns="foo")
result <- base::eval(call)
```

But suppose that package `foo` has a *variable* named `a` which is just a character vector. The same setup no longer works:

```
call <- rlang::call2(.fn="a",.ns="foo")
result <- base::eval(call)
# Error in base::eval(call) : attempt to apply non-function
```

For example:

- package = `phyloseq`
- variable = `distanceMethodList`

```
call <- rlang::call2(.fn="distanceMethodList",.ns="phyloseq")
result <- base::eval(call)
# Error in base::eval(call) : attempt to apply non-function
```

Comment: Something like this [calling methods from other pkgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452820/referring-to-package-and-function-as-arguments-in-another-function)?, which doesn't solve the problem that the other package has to be around.

Comment: @cmo: Did the link above solve your problem? If not, what is your ultimate goal? To use an object from a package without relying on `package::objectname`, because this won't pass `R CMD check`?